# Measuring impedance of wire/cable

Tags: filter, impedance, common-mode

I'm working on an audio project where I'd like to install common-mode filters consisting of a cm choke and 2 caps to chassis at each of the input connectors in order to shunt common-mode noise picked up by the cables to the earth grounded enclosure. In order to get an idea of the frequency response, I want to simulate the CM-filters with source and load impedances. I have measured values of the common-mode load impedances at the device inputs, and would like to measure the impedance of the cable (acting as the source impedance, most likely twisted pair (unterminated)) across a range of frequencies, from 1MHz to about 30MHz (or more).

I don't have a spectrum analyzer, but I have a 30MHz signal generator and a 100Mhz scope. What's the best way to measure this? I was thinking something similar to the setup below:

[image]

I'd measure V across Rmeas to get current, varying Rmeas relative to cable impedance to get enough voltage drop to get an accurate reading, then move Rmeas to the other end of the cable and measure Vin across the cable. Sound reasonable? I assume I'm going to be loading the generator heavily, would it be better to add a buffer at the front end, or is this really necessary?

Comment: Why don't you start with specs?  - for the required SNR of the signal or expected level of noise interference or required level of crosstalk.  Then you choose balanced differential driver, cable and load and then choose the impedance of Balun or CM choke in order to reduce the differential crosstalk due to improvement in balanced impedance  then choose the cable impedance and value of choke and caps required to achieve the initial requirement.  If impedances are mismatched everywhere, then at least they must be balanced.  When you want to find the impedance you create an R ratio with a known R

Comment: Start with cable specs for STP or UTP for differential and CM. Many are 120 ohm. What are your source and load Z(f)'s?  Did you know that cable impedance \$Z=\sqrt {\frac{L}{C}}\$

Comment: I have filter designs based on the range of frequencies I want to filter out with specific components chosen, I've modeled them using the known cm load resistance (from measurement, verified against calculations) and plotted results with wide range of varying source resistances, and more-or-less the response shape is acceptable. But I want to have at very minimum a measured source impedance curve so I have a better idea of what to expect.

Comment: Yes correct about the characteristic impedance but in this application these cables are not being used as properly terminated transmission lines, they're being used to transfer audio signals that could pick radiated noise along the length. I'm trying to get an approximate curve of some different cables and lengths that someone might use to interconnect devices. We're talking just the average joe picking up a set of twisted pair cable to use for audio signals. I just want to make sure that my methodology for measuring works.

Comment: If your source is near 0 Ohms and load near 8 Ohms  then a 50 ohm source will not measure correctly.

Comment: assume it's a single conductor, pretend it's a radio antenna.

Comment: @Tony Stewart: Maybe having a brain fart here, but as long as I can draw enough current from the 50 Ohm source, what difference does it make on the measurement if I'm loading it? The shunt resistance would need to be the correct impedance to get an accurate reading, but I'm measuring the voltage going into the cable and the current going through it, and calculating impedance from there. What difference does it make if the source is supplying 10V vs. 1V to the load from being loaded down?

Comment: You seem to want to measure noise ingress on long audio cables from any source of interference. Yet you have not defined interference, ground path , mutual coupling of cable interference. Meanwhile there are conducted and radiated sources sources of interference that have nothing to do with your measurement.

Comment: @Tony Stewart: If I were to sit down with you and have a discussion to fill in my knowledge gaps, it would certainly take a few hours. When I post too much info in a single post trying to fill in those gaps, I generally get tidbits of answers/pieces of information which leave me scratching my head for days on end, trying to put them into a context and make sense of them. That's why I'm trying to ask concrete questions in steps to get the info I need to finish this project. For now, all I want to know is the best way to measure wire/cable impedance using the equipment I have above.

Comment: Or to at least get a somewhat ballpark estimate (doesn't have to be perfect) so I have a general idea of what I'm dealing with. I find measurements indispensable for confirming my interpretation of datasheet values and calculations.

Comment: The test plan you show is not going to give you Common mode impedance.  This is not a common mode signal.  It is only 1/2 of the differential impedance as the dual paths are shown to share the same current.  This is basically just an inductance/meter and a milliohm /meter reading since there is no ground plane shown and very little capacitance to ground current expected.  However if you put a DC current probe around the wire pair, then you can measure CM current but only if the wire pair is terminated at both ends and there is some power signal circulating.

Comment: I found an article from the best company that teaches EMC that backs up my comments above http://www.hottconsultants.com/techtips/tips-cm.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71206/discussion-between-user7251-and-tony-stewart-ee-since-75).